# Does an index of this array exist?

Tags: c#, arrays, indexing

I've inherited some code at work that has a really bad smell.  I'm hoping to find the most painless solution possible.

Is there a way to check if some arbitrary number is a valid element in an array?

Example - I need to check if array[25] exists.

Preferably I would prefer to do this without doing a foreach() through the array to find the rows.

Is there a way to do this, or am I stuck with a *foreach* loop?

Comment: Do you mean you want to know if some value for array[x] == 25? 

I think you are confusing people about what you are asking for by asking if array[25] exists. Certainly it exists if there are 26 or more elements in the array, but I don't think that is what you are asking for.

Comment: The program I'm working in has two possible arrays that have the same filename.  One has 21 elements and the Other has 30something.  I need the value at array[25] should it exist.

Comment: Many answers seem redundant, but they are from a time when it was not uncommon with seven answers ***in about two minutes***... (thus they are excused). But that is not the case for *some* of the answers submitted more than five ***years*** later.

Answer (score 170, accepted):

Test the length

```
int index = 25;
if(index < array.Length)
{
    //it exists
}
```

Comment: Thanks.  I can't believe I didn't think of the .Length property!

Comment: Make sure that index >= 0 as well.

Comment: And make sure the array itself isn't null :)

Comment: Because Array indexes are required to be sequential in C# this is true.  There are collection types that don't have sequential indexes, but those aren't basic Array types in C#.

Answer (score 149):

You can use [LINQ](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Language_Integrated_Query) to achieve that too:

```
var exists = array.ElementAtOrDefault(index) != null;
```

Comment: Thanks, this is what I was looking for instead of the clumsy array length check.

Comment: Minor note, `new object[]{ null }.ElementAtOrDefault(index)` will return `null` since the element at 0 **is** `null`. Using `ElementAtOrDefault` is not a great solution for checking array indices *exist*, that equality check added to the end makes the results indeterminable.

Comment: @ChrisMarisic Can you please give an example?

Comment: @ChrisMarisic you're right, in case you wanna check for existence only do `array.Length > index`.

Comment: @ChrisMarisic, actually this is a major note, solutions like this will lead to hidden bugs

Comment: @amd it worked fine for me because i was working with structs at the time, but yes this has big pitfalls for classes.

Comment: How would this work for  2D arrays? ElementAtOrDefault(index1,index2) ?

Comment: Default might by zero

Answer (score 25):

What exactly do you mean by "is a valid element"? You could just do:

```
if (array.Length >= 26)
```

which would tell you whether 25 is a valid index into the array or not (assuming a 0 lower bound).

If you need to know whether it's non-null or not, just use:

```
if (array[25] != null)
```

(or a combination of the two).

If these don't help, please give a more precise meaning of "valid" for your problem.

Comment: for second example i got this. `Index was outside the bounds of the array`

Comment: @raheel: Well then it sounds like you should have been using the first test instead...

Answer (score 13):

Assuming you also want to check if the item is not null

```
if (array.Length > 25 && array[25] != null)
{
    //it exists
}
```

Comment: Note: Got to use `&&` in `if (array.Length > 25 && array[25] != null)`, if use single `&` will throw IndexOutOfRange exception. [MSDN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/2a723cdk.aspx).

Answer (score 5):

```
// I'd modify this slightly to be more resilient to a bad parameter
// it will handle your case and better handle other cases given to it:

int index = 25;

if (index >= 0 && index < array.Length)
{
    // Array element found
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Because ElementAtOrDefault() will return null if does not exists, this could lead to unintended consequences.

I use to do in a single line:

```
string sval = array.ElementAtOrDefault(index) ?? "" //for strings
int ival = array.ElementAtOrDefault(index) ?? 0 //for ints
. . . //etc
```

Comment: I am using this but getting this error Operator '??' cannot be applied to operands of type 'int' and 'int'

Answer (score 1):

You can use the length of the array, and see if your arbitrary number fits in that range.  For example, if you have an array of size 10, then array[25] isn't valid because 25 is not less than 10.

Answer (score 1):

You can rather use a List, so you can check the existence.

```
List<int> l = new List<int>();
l.Add(45);
...
...

if (l.Count == 25) {
  doStuff();
}
int num = 45;
if (l.Contains(num)) {
  doMoreStuff();
}
```

Answer (score 1):

`array.length` will tell you how many elements are in an array

Answer (score 1):

The answers here are straightforward, but they only apply to a one-dimensional array.

For multi-dimensional arrays, checking for null is a straightforward way to tell if the element exists. The example code here checks for null. Note the try/catch block is (probably) overkill, but it makes the block bomb-proof.

```
public ItemContext GetThisElement(int row,
    int col)
{
    ItemContext ctx = null;
    if (rgItemCtx[row, col] != null)
    {
        try
        {
          ctx = rgItemCtx[row, col];
        }
        catch (SystemException sex)
        {
          ctx = null;
          // Perhaps do something with sex properties
        }
    }

    return (ctx);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You could check if the index is less than the length of the array.  This doesn't check for nulls or other odd cases where the index can be assigned a value but hasn't been given one explicitly.

Answer (score 0):

You can check the length of the array to see if item 25 is valid in the sense of being in the array, then you could use

```
if (array.Length > 25)
{ 
   if (array[25] != null)
   {
       //good
   }
}
```

to see if the array item itself has been set.

Answer (score 0):

It sounds very much like you're using an array to store different fields. This is definitely a code smell. I'd avoid using arrays as much as possible as they're generally not suitable (or needed) in high-level code.

Switching to a simple Dictionary may be a workable option in the short term. As would using a big property bag class. There are lots of options. The problem you have now is just a symptom of bad design, and you should look at fixing the underlying problem rather than just patching the bad design, so it kinda, sorta mostly works, for now.