# How can I check if an array index is out of range?

Tags: c#, arrays

How can I check if an array index is out of range? Or prevent it happening.

Comment: Check the length.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Does Index of Array Exist](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/794760/does-index-of-array-exist)

Comment: How can i do that? p.s. it is reciving information from databse

Comment: If this is about getting data from a DB , then you need to change your question to include that information.

Comment: no no, it not about getting data from a DB, everything with the DB is al working fine, i just want ot jnow how to check if an array is out of range or not, and if not, code code code

Comment: This feels like you are falling into the [XY Problem](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem). Sure, you can check [`Array.Length`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.array.length(v=vs.110).aspx) to avoid using an index that is out of range. But judging from your comment you have an issue where you are using an incorrect index in the first place, where are you getting this index from and what's causing it to be out of range? You don't seem keen on posting any code though and the question has been answered. Good luck.

Comment: You can also clamp the index as in index = Mathf.Clamp(index ,0,array.Length); But that is not valid if you mean to skip the action when the index is not in range.

Comment: I've created an extenssion method: public static T ElementAtOrDef<T>(this IEnumerable<T> arr, int idx, int defIndx = 0)
        {
            if (arr.Count() > idx)
                return arr.ElementAt(idx);
            return arr.ElementAt(defIndx);
        }

but you can use also the built in "ElementAtOrDefault" which does something different

Answer (score 25):

```
int index = 99;
if(index >= 0 && index < array.Length)
{
    //it exists
}
```

Source: [Does an index of this array exist?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/794760/does-index-of-array-exist)

Comment: <3 Thanks, thats it, but i have to check on multiple arrays at the sametime, and if it is right according to the DB. But i figured it out. Thanks anyway. Take Care!

Comment: For future reference, if you find another question that you believe has the exact answer, *don't* duplicate that answer into your own answer. Instead, click the "flag" option under a question, choose "Flag to close > Duplicate question", and choose the appropriate question.

Comment: it will fail when someone passes any value less than `0`. so need an additional check as `index >= 0` which combines the if statement to become `if(index >= 0 && index < array.Length){}`

Comment: Related: *[Answers entirely copied though properly attributed](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/321299/)* - e.g., *"...simply tacking a "Reference" link at...a wall of unquoted text...does not count as proper attribution"*.

Comment: The magic number, 25, comes from [the corresponding question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/794760/).

Comment: I prefer to write `if(0 <= index && index < array.Length)`, for simmetry, math-like style, and (in my mind) clarity of "index is inside the semiopen interval [0, Length)".

Comment: @PeterMortensen noted that and as mentioned in the answer itself. I gave the source while posting the answer, I never said its mine.

Comment: @Serlite noted, will take care of it next time onwards.

Answer (score 13):

Another way of checking if an array is out of bounds is to make a function. This will check if the index is "in bounds". If the index is below zero or over the array length you will get the result **false**.

```
private bool inBounds (int index, int[] array) 
{
    return (index >= 0) && (index < array.Length);
}
```

Comment: This should be built in as a member function of the array class..

Comment: what if it is int[,]?

Answer (score 7):

Correct way would be

```
int index = 25;
if (index >= 0 && index < array.Length)
{}
```

Comment: Typo there array.Length not array.Legth (being picky)

Comment: It seems like a rehashing of [the copied answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42536752/how-can-i-check-if-an-array-index-is-out-of-range/42536826#42536826) (a copy of a copy). The magic number, 25, comes from [the corresponding question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/794760/).

Comment: @PeterMortensen I don't get what you mean - if what you trying to say is that I copied the answer that's incorrect

Comment: @PeterMortensen aren't you posting same comment to all answers ;)