# how to handle the empty list, List Alternated[0] throws exception while assigning empty value to C2

Tags: c#

Var Alternated have the list of files

```
//Split the Files
    var Alternated = Files
                    .Select((name, index) => new { name, index })
                    .GroupBy(item => item.index % 2, item => item.name)
                    .Select(group => group.ToList())
                    .ToArray();
```

If the variable have a single value, Alternated[1] throws exception how to handle the empty list Alternated[1]

```
//Assigning alternate files to the variable  
var C1 = Alternated[0];
var C2 = Alternated[1];
```

Comment: What is the type of value present in list `Alternated`?

Comment: you can use ElementAtOrDefault, for more information look at [Does Index of Array Exist](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/794760/does-index-of-array-exist)

Comment: Have you looked what's going on using the debugger. It's a little hard to imagine the contents of your data from here

Comment: type of value present in list Alternated is string(List of file names)

Comment: Why do you want to assign array element to the varibles, you can directly use array element in for loop? otherwise you need to check index which you are trying to use is less than array length or not?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [ElementAtOrDefault](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.linq.enumerable.elementatordefault?view=netframework-4.8).

```
var C1 = Alternated.ElementAtOrDefault(0);
var C2 = Alternated.ElementAtOrDefault(1);
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
string[] C = new string[Alternated.Length];

    for (int i = 0; i < C.Length; i++)
        C[i] = Alternated[i].ToString();
```