# Shorten repetitive exception handling with WPF components

Tags: c#, wpf

I am working with the WPF project, it's kinda annoying to have the same repetitive exception handling that only number makes it different?

Here's the code:

```cs
try
{
    filling_head_model1.Text = models[0].Model;
    filling_head_type1.Text = "1. " + models[0].Type;
    filling_head_subtype1.Text = models[0].SubType;
    filling_head_image1.Source = defaultImage;
} 
catch (IndexOutOfRangeException)
{
    filling_head_model1.Text = null;
    filling_head_type1.Text = null;
    filling_head_subtype1.Text = null;
    filling_head_image1.Source = null;
}

try
{
    filling_head_model2.Text = models[1].Model;
    filling_head_type2.Text = "2. " + models[1].Type;
    filling_head_subtype2.Text = models[1].SubType;
    filling_head_image2.Source = defaultImage;
}
catch (IndexOutOfRangeException)
{
    filling_head_model2.Text = null;
    filling_head_type2.Text = null;
    filling_head_subtype2.Text = null;
    filling_head_image2.Source = null;
}
... // there are 5 more
```

As you can see the only thing changed is the number at the back that represents each component. I know how to change the index of the array using loops, but how do I change the number at the back of the component name programmatically?

Comment: Instead of `try/catch` you can simply check [if such index exists](https://stackoverflow.com/q/794760/1997232). In general you should only use `try/catch` for something *unexpected*. Here you expect what item may be missing.

Comment: Put the components in an array as well

Comment: good idea thanks @Erno

Comment: Sure ill try @Sinatr

Comment: Putting the UI elements in an array is a terrible idea. In general, and especially because you would need four arrays for the four different types.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't need the `try/catch` at all.

Just use an ItemsControl with an appropriate ItemTemplate.

```
<ItemsControl x:Name="itemsControl">
    <ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
        <DataTemplate>
            <StackPanel>
                <TextBlock Text="{Binding Model}"/>
                <TextBlock>
                    <Run Text="{Binding Number}"/><Run Text="."/>
                    <Run Text="{Binding Type}"/>
                </TextBlock>
                <TextBlock Text="{Binding SubType}"/>
                <Image Source="{Binding Image}"/>
            </StackPanel>
        </DataTemplate>
    </ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>    
</ItemsControl>
```

and assign the `models` collection to its ItemsSource:

```
itemsControl.ItemsSource = models;
```

Note that the model members must be public properties.